# Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/x-js

Tags: javascript, jquery, mime-types, flowplayer

I get this warning only on distant server

> Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/x-js

I'm using wamp 2.1 and work correctly

Video not working on distant one
I can't use probably htacess if necessary to solve this problem cause it's shared server

Header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.11.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-1.7.1.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../flowplayer/flowplayer.playlist-3.2.10.min.js"></script>
```

(I have changed path just for the example)

The order is it important (flowplayer before jquery here)?
Or json structure it may be the cause of problem?

Comment: thanks Cerbrus, any improvement are welcome

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a warning and not an error. Is it preventing the script from executing?
The error is definetly a server configuration one, so if you can't get someone to fix the server, you'll have to put up with the warning.

Comment: create a test javascript file on the server that does something simple like call `alert()` or do a `document.write()`. Then remove all the script tags from your document and replace them with one that loads this test script. See if that fires. If it does, then the warning is unrelated to your scripts not executing. It may also help to not use the `.min` versions of the libraries, so you can find the error.

Comment: thx @Nicholas , I will do it when I will have access to the server by my Chief and tell you about the result